# How do I create a non-blocking DragGesture on a sheet?

Tags: swiftui

I have added a DragGesture to a View in a sheet like this:

```
.sheet(isPresented: $sheetIsPresented) {
    ZStack {
        Rectangle()
            .scaledToFill()
            .foregroundColor(Color.red)
    }
    .gesture(
        DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0).onChanged({ _ in
            print("Drag")
        }).onEnded({ _ in
            print("Drag ended")
        })
    )
}
```

This blocks the sheet from being dismissed interactively. As is the intended functionality.

How can I both keep the default interactive dismissal functionality of the sheet and at the same time get access to the DragGesture?

I don't need drag coordinates, I just need to detect when a user holds down on the View inside the sheet and when they release, but I want to allow them to close the sheet interactively while holding down.

Comment: have you looked into `simultaneousgesture` see: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/simultaneousgesture

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine as in changing `.gesture` with `.simultaneousGesture`? yeah, same result.

Comment: What behaviour do you want to achieve? How should the system determine if you drag your sheet view or if you want it to dismiss? In other words: can you constrain your inner drag gesture to a specific part of the sheet?

Comment: @ChrisR the View on the sheet is similar to an Instagram story and I want to let users pause it by holding down. But they should also be able to swipe away the sheet while holding down. I guess it looks like I can’t use a sheet for this and have to implement a custom overlay with animations and what not